# Why am I getting a "permission denied" trying to access a shared folder in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, shared-folders

I'm using **VirtualBox** and I'm trying to run a program (that I wrote in C on my host machine) on a guest machine using **Lubuntu 16.04 in CLI**. In order to do so I need to share the project folder with the guest machine, but I'm having several problems to access it.

I created a shared folder with the given menu in VBox, with a correct path, naming it "MyProjectFolder". Moving with `cd` and `ls` inside the guest OS I managed to find `/media/sf_MyProjectFolder` but whenever I try to access it I get a **permission denied** error.

Running:

```
$ cd sf_MyProjectFolder`
```

I get:

```
-bash: cd: sf_MyProjectFolder/: Permission denied
```

I tried with `chmod` but I still get permission problems. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would update your question to include the output of the `ls -ld /media/sf_MyProjectFolder` and `groups` commands.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding yourself to the "vboxsf" group within the guest VM:

```bsh
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf $(whoami)
```

Note that you have to log out and log back in for this to take effect. After logging back in, check to make sure that you've been added to the group by running the `groups` command.

If that doesn't work, try checking the permissions on the directory:

```bsh
ls -ld /media/sf_MyProjectFolder
```

The [VirtualBox Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/) has a [chapter on Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) which has a [section that covers shared folders](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders).

Also note that this question has been asked elsewhere on StackExchange, e.g. on StackOverflow:

- [Virtualbox shared folder permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740113/virtualbox-shared-folder-permissions)